# Error al leer un archivo .sql

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

Buenas noches Comunidad.

Tengo un programa en java, al cual se paso como argumento el archivo authors.sql (base de datos en postgresql) el cual contiene una sola línea:

```
INSERT INTO authors VALUES ('CEVA', 'K.', 'Cherteston')
```

al momento de leer la instrucción y ejecutar la sentencia INSERT INTO, me arroja la siguiente excepción:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near
>   "INSERT"   Position: 1

**¿Alguien observa algo erróneo en el contenido del archivo authors.sql?**

Les adjunto una imagen que muestra la línea donde se produce la excepción así como también el string que contiene la sentencia sql INSERT INTO, espero que ayude.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

gracias por su tiempo

Comment: En el contenido del Archivo `sql ` No, pero quizá el error está en la forma en la realiza el `query` (como le pasas el valor y como lees la línea de tu archivo) empleando Java

Comment: hice la prueba ingresando en modo hard code la sentencia sql y realizó la inserción. El problema está la leer esa línea del archivo .sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al ver tus comentarios, entiendo que tu problema solo sucede cuando lees la sentencia de tu archivo `authors.sql`.

De ser el caso, es muy probable que el problema se deba a que se está introduciendo un carácter invisible cuándo lees la sentencia del archivo.

Por ejemplo, puede que tu archivo esté en el formato UTF-8, y puede que incluya un BOM (byte order mark) al principio del archivo.

En este caso, tu variable `line` comenzaría con el carácter [`U+FEFF`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/FEFF/index.htm). Y como se trata de un carácter invisible, es fácil no darse cuenta que está allí. Si quieres confirmar su presencia, evalúa la expresión siguiente:

```
(int)line.charAt(0); // contiene 65279?
```

Si te devuelve `65279`, ya sabes que ese es el problema.

Para resolver el problema, puedes editar tu archivo para quitarle el BOM al principio. Varios editores te permiten hacer esto.

O, puedes eliminarlo en tu código usando `String.replace`:

```
stmt.execute(line.replace("\uFEFF", ""));
```

Comment: Efectivamente @sstan, me retorna el codigo 65279. apliqué la línea de código que me sugieres: line.replace("\uFEFF", "") pero me da el mismo error. org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "INSERT"
  Position: 1

Comment: @David: ¿Probastes: `stmt.execute(line.replace("\uFEFF", ""));`? O ¿ejecutastes `line.replace("\uFEFF", "")` separadamente, y luego `stmt.execute(line)`? También cabe la posibilidad de que haya otro caracter incorrecto. Pudieras examinar el string caracter por caracter para ver donde esta el problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias @sstan, cambié mi código por la línea: stmt.execute(line.replace("\uFEFF", "")) y funcionó. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

La sintaxis correcta es:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (column1, column2, column3,...columnN)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...valueN);
```

en tu caso sería algo así:

```
INSERT INTO authors (nombre, apellidoPaterno,apellidoMaterno) VALUES ('CEVA', 'K.', 'Cherteston')
```

O si tienes 1 solo campo:

```
INSERT INTO authors (nombre) VALUES ('CEVA');
INSERT INTO authors (nombre) VALUES ('K.');
INSERT INTO authors (nombre) VALUES ('Cherteston');
```

Tutorial recomendado para aprender PostgreSQL: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/index.htm

Comment: Se puede realizar el query sin especificar el nombre de los campos de la tabla. Pero asegúrandose de que el orden de los valores está en el mismo orden que las columnas de la tabla.

Comment: gracias por el dato :D